Eigenvalue related problem
$$  T=d i a g ( \beta ) W ^ { T } ( d i a g ( W \beta ) ) ^ { - 1 } W $$where $diag(\beta)$
is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix,which is positive definite,and W is a stochastic matrix. I have been able to show that T has an eigenvalue equal to 1 and its corresponding eigenvector is ${\bf{1}}_{n \times 1}$
$$\begin{array}{c}
{{\bf{1}}_{n \times 1}} \cdot T = {{\bf{1}}_{n \times 1}} \cdot \left[ {diag(\beta ){W^T}{{(diag(W\beta ))}^{ - 1}}W} \right]\\
 = {(\beta )^T}{W^T}{(diag(W\beta ))^{ - 1}}W\\
 = {(W\beta )^T}{(diag(W\beta ))^{ - 1}}W\\
 = {{\bf{1}}_{n \times 1}}W\\
 = {{\bf{1}}_{n \times 1}}
\end{array}$$
Now I want to show that all its other eigenvalues are strictly less than 1, wouldn't this prove the convergence of the status transition matrix,but I don't know how to do that!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

You should show the work related to what you've done so far. How did you show that $T$ has an eigenvalue equal to $1$? When you say that $W$ is a random matrix, do you by any chance mean that it is a stochastic matrix?

@José Carlos Santos
I sincerely thank you for responding to this question, and I've made a correction in response to the above question.

@John Barber Thank you!!I have shown the work that has been done
